Macbook Pro 2016 running Windows 10 (Bootcamp) shuts off in sleep or hibernation
I have a Macbook Pro 2016 15-inch touchbar that is running a fresh install of Windows 10 via Bbootcamp with all drivers installed via the bootcamp software.
Everything works great, except the fact that when the computer is asleep or in hibernation for a while, it seems to crash and shut off, and I see when turning it back on that all my programs/tabs are closed, and the OS reports that Windows had not been properly shut down.
I have searched all over online for any records of anyone else having this issue and I have come up blank.
Fast-startup is disabled, and the funny thing is that everything is fine when I wake the computer up within a short period of time after sleep or hibernate, but after leaving it for maybe 15 minutes or more the problem can arise; however it seems to be inconsistent, and hibernate seems to be a bit more reliable.
Any help would be appreciated.
